# Выборка сущьности с невалидным id записи Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteriabuilder

**Есть такой код:**

```
@Override
public Category findById(Client client, Long id) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Category> query = builder.createQuery(Category.class);

    Root<Category> root = query.from(Category.class);

    query.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id))
            .where(builder.and(builder.equal(root.get("client"), client)));

    query.select(root);

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).uniqueResultOptional().orElse(null);
}
```

Если я передаю `id` = `null` то находит первую запись, а не возвращает `null`.

Почему?

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что вы неправильно пишите предикат `where`. Надо делать так

```
query.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), id),
        builder.equal(root.get("client"), client));
```